# Missing items in Notifications response

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-fql

I'm trying to retrieve the list of all notifications using FQL. I have manage_notifications permission. If I do a query, like:

```
SELECT notification_id, sender_id, created_time, updated_time, is_unread, title_html, title_text, href, icon_url from notification where recipient_id = me()
```

it works. But the returned list is missing some items, seemingly at random. Some notifications that are present on the Facebook website just don't appear in the output. I can't spot any pattern in which ones are being skipped. But if I use the regular Graph API to call /me/notifications?include_read=1 exactly the same entries are missing.

I'm getting the same result whether I call from my code or using the Graph Explorer. What's more, if the skipped notification is unread, I can query the unread count and get "1", even though the notification in question does not appear in the list.

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug, possibly related to newer notifications from Timeline etc. You should file a report in the [Facebook Platform Bug Tracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs) and link back here to let everyone know where the issue is being tracked.